# php if in an option tag

Tags: php

hi can anyone help me with this? i really had a hard time putting my if statement in this code

```
<select name="date_opened_year">
<?php 
define('DOB_YEAR_START', 1962);
$current_year = date('Y');

for ($count = $current_year; $count >= DOB_YEAR_START; $count--)
{
    echo "<option value='{$count}'>{$count}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

and i have here a code where i had put my if statement

```
<select name="date_opened_year">
<?php 
define('DOB_YEAR_START', 1962);
$current_year = date('Y');

for ($count = $current_year; $count >= DOB_YEAR_START; $count--)
{
    echo "<option value='{$count}' if($yy == $count) echo 'selected'>{$count}</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

$yy = 2003 well it comes from a query in the database and when i look at the code it gives me something like this

```
<option 'selected'="" echo="" 2012)="" if(2003="=" value="2012">2012</option>
```

why is that? can anyone revise the code? thanks

Comment: `$yy` looks like it's undefined. What value is it supposed to be?

Comment: PHP code does not get evaluated like that. Try `printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $count, ($yy == $count) ? 'selected' : '', $count)`.

Comment: like i said diggers $yy = 2003 <-- the data comes from a query

Comment: there we go thanks DCoder :) why don't you post the answer so i can accept that ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$selectStr = ($yy == $count) ? 'selected': '';
echo "<option value='".$count."' ".$selectStr.">".$count."</option>";
```

Best to break it up.

You've got your if inside a string creation double quote.

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
if($yy == $count){ 
   echo "<option value='{$count}' selected='selected'>{$count}</option>";
}
```

Comment: hmm this is okay doniyor but it will destroy the other data like only 2003 with display and not 2002,2001 or 2004 2005 and so on.. but its a good one thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Echo will not evaluate if statement. Try @DCoder solution with printf or this:

```
echo "<option value='{$count}'";
if($yy == $count) echo 'selected';
echo ">{$count}</option>";
```